# How to create a list with the same element n-times?

Tags: scala

How to create a list with the same element n-times ?

Manually implementnation:

```
scala> def times(n: Int, s: String) =
 | (for(i <- 1 to n) yield s).toList
times: (n: Int, s: String)List[String]

scala> times(3, "foo")
res4: List[String] = List(foo, foo, foo)
```

Is there also a built-in way to do the same ?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

See [scala.collection.generic.SeqFactory.fill(n:Int)(elem: =>A)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/SeqFactory.html#fill[A](n:Int)(elem:=>A):CC[A]) that collection data structures, like `Seq`, `Stream`, `Iterator` and so on, extend:

```
scala> List.fill(3)("foo")
res1: List[String] = List(foo, foo, foo)
```

**WARNING** It's not available in Scala 2.7.

Comment: See GenTraversableFactory for more info, and #14 on this page: http://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/scala-snippets/

Answer (score 15):

```
(1 to n).map( _ => "foo" )
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Why is it wasteful?

Comment: @k0pernikus Because the value of `_` does not actually matter. You could do `n to 1 by -1`, `-1 to -n by -1`, etc.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte In the end, one needs a temporary loop variable. Even the `fill` method's implementation constructs a temporary variable internally whose value would not matter as long as it produces the right amount in the list. So I don't mind the unused  `_`.

Comment: @k0pernikus I wouldn't mind it either on the local Scala REPL or in a Scastie snippet. But on a professional project, I would consider it reason enough for refactoring.

Answer (score 13):

Using `tabulate` like this,

```
List.tabulate(3)(_ => "foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer which emulates flatMap I think (found out that this solution returns Unit when applying duplicateN)

```
 implicit class ListGeneric[A](l: List[A]) {
  def nDuplicate(x: Int): List[A] = {
    def duplicateN(x: Int, tail: List[A]): List[A] = {
      l match {
       case Nil => Nil
       case n :: xs => concatN(x, n) ::: duplicateN(x, xs)
    }
    def concatN(times: Int, elem: A): List[A] = List.fill(times)(elem)
  }
  duplicateN(x, l)
}
```

}

```
def times(n: Int, ls: List[String]) = ls.flatMap{ List.fill(n)(_) }
```

but this is rather for a predetermined List and you want to duplicate n times each element